# How to login to a website using Python- Requests

Tags: python, html, authentication, automation, python-requests

**I am trying to login to a web app using Python to authenticate however I am getting the following error "Your credentials are incorrect or have expired. Please try again"
Any help would be most appreciated**

```
import requests

loginURL = ('https://signin.ea.com/p/juno/login?execution=e1653929912s1&initref=https%3A%2F%2Faccounts.ea.com%3A443%2Fconnect%2Fauth%3Fhide_create%3Dtrue%26display%3Dweb2%252Flogin%26scope%3Dbasic.identity%2Boffline%2Bsignin%2Bbasic.entitlement%2Bbasic.persona%26release_type%3Dprod%26response_type%3Dtoken%26redirect_uri%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fwww.ea.com%252Fea-sports-fc%252Fultimate-team%252Fweb-app%252Fauth.html%26accessToken%3D%26locale%3Den_US%26prompt%3Dlogin%26client_id%3DFC24_JS_WEB_APP')

payload = {
    'email': 'email@ymail.com',
    'password': 'password123',
    '_eventId': 'submit',
    'cid': 'd6B7rH33TXTEguTcoDLSJEzT0qZzikXd,t4zprDsDRWCb4S33E5LsX89FtIgyFoeo',
    'showAgeUp': 'true',
    'thirdPartyCaptchaResponse': '',
    'loginMethod': 'emailPassword',
    '_rememberMe': 'on'
}

r = requests.post(loginURL, data=payload)

print(r.text)
```

[image: Below is the form details taken from the post message via Google Networks:]